# Azure Maps - Render - Get Map Image - How to apply multiple colors to different pins

Tags: c#, .net, azure, bing-maps, azure-maps

I have two pins on different locations on my map image from azure maps, when i apply a color to it, all the pins get same color, i want to apply different colors to each pin, I am using Azure Maps REST service to get the image of the map.

**URL**:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?api-version=1.0&style=main&layer=basic&zoom=14&height=700&Width=700&center=-122.13230609893799,47.64599069048016&path=lcFF0000|lw2|la0.60|ra1000||-122.13230609893799 47.64599069048016&pins=default|la15+50|al0.66|lc003C62|co002D62||'Microsoft Corporate Headquarters'-122.14131832122801  47.64690503939462|'Microsoft Visitor Center'-122.136828 47.642224|'Microsoft Conference Center'-122.12552547454833 47.642940335653996|'Microsoft The Commons'-122.13687658309935  47.64452336193245&subscription-key={subscription-key}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your data into two `pins` parameters (you can specify it more than once in a URL). For example:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?api-version=1.0&style=main&layer=basic&zoom=14&height=700&Width=700&center=-122.13230609893799,47.64599069048016&path=lcFF0000|lw2|la0.60|ra1000||-122.13230609893799 47.64599069048016&pins=default|la15+50|al0.66|lc003C62|co002D62||'Microsoft Corporate Headquarters'-122.14131832122801 47.64690503939462|'Microsoft Visitor Center'-122.136828 47.642224&pins=default|la15+50|al0.66|lcff0000|coff0000||'Microsoft Conference Center'-122.12552547454833 47.642940335653996|'Microsoft The Commons'-122.13687658309935 47.64452336193245&subscription-key={subscription-key}
```